# Spring Integration: configure default errorChannel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

when starting the spring boot integration project on which I’m working on, following Info log is shown:

```
No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
```

Is there a way to configure the queue name for this default Bean using only yaml/json paramenters, without explicitly create the Bean?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not; you explicity need to declare a `MessageChannel` bean named `errorChannel` to replace the default error channel and its configuration.